# Kapacitor alert using derivative value

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I am trying to generate alert when the Cisco router's interface throughput exceeds certain value. Please have a look at my code.

I am using telegraph to collect the data. My measurement "monitor usage" contains multiple field keys and values. How to separate them and alert on each of them? Am I using "derivative" node correctly? Is it the field key I should use in the "derivative" node?

Is there a way to log each node output to help troubleshooting? In my case, how do I see "bytes_recv_per_sec" value as being calculated by the "alert" node?

What does "log" node do exactly? Where is the log file? I don't see much valuable information in "/var/log/kapacitor/kapacitor.log"

I have tried playing with different nodes with different parameter methods without much success. Thanks for any help.

```
dbrp "telegraf"."autogen"

stream
    |from()
        .measurement('monitor usage')
        .where(lambda: "agent_host" == '10.92.192.15')
    |window()
      .period(1m)
      .every(1m)
    |httpOut('dump')
    |stats(1m)
    |httpOut('stats')
    |derivative('Envision_Po1.891_ifHCInOctets')
        .unit(1s).nonNegative()
        .as('bytes_recv_per_sec')
    |alert()
        .warn(lambda: "bytes_recv_per_sec" > 40.0)
        .crit(lambda: "bytes_recv_per_sec" > 80.0)
         // post to logfile
        .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
```

At this stage I want to see "/tmp/alerts.log" to generate some alert message when the alert threshold is met. Eventually I want to send an alert email.

As per request, here is info about my database on the "monitor usage" measurement

```
> show series from "monitor usage";
key
---
monitor\ usage,agent_host=10.85.1.5,host=dzhao-trex,sw_name=it-na-wan-pro-01-11p.int.pason.com
monitor\ usage,agent_host=10.85.1.6,host=dzhao-trex,sw_name=it-na-wan-pro-02-11p.int.pason.com
monitor\ usage,agent_host=10.92.192.15,host=dzhao-trex,rtr_name=irt01-00rm255r2r1.int.pason.com
monitor\ usage,agent_host=10.92.192.17,host=dzhao-trex,sw_name=wsw01-00rm255r2r1.pason.com
monitor\ usage,agent_host=172.19.254.200,host=dzhao-trex,sw_name=ssw01-04rm120r7.int.pason.com
monitor\ usage,agent_host=192.168.195.1,host=dzhao-trex,sw_name=wrt01-06.int.pason.com

> show field keys from "monitor usage";
name: monitor usage
fieldKey                           fieldType
--------                           ---------
Envision_Po1.891_ifHCInOctets      integer
Envision_Po1.891_ifHCOutOctets     integer
Gi0/0/0_ifHCInOctets               integer
Gi0/0/0_ifHCOutOctets              integer
GigabitEthernet0/0/0_ifHCInOctets  integer
GigabitEthernet0/0/0_ifHCOutOctets integer
GigabitEthernet0/0/2_ifHCInOctets  integer
GigabitEthernet0/0/2_ifHCOutOctets integer
HE_Po1.892_ifHCInOctets            integer
HE_Po1.892_ifHCOutOctets           integer
Po1003_ifHCInOctets                integer
Po1003_ifHCOutOctets               integer
Rogers_Po1.894_ifHCInOctets        integer
Rogers_Po1.894_ifHCOutOctets       integer
Shaw_Po1.893_ifHCInOctets          integer
Shaw_Po1.893_ifHCOutOctets         integer
Te2/5/6_ifHCInOctets               integer
Te2/5/6_ifHCOutOctets              integer
Tunnel100_ifHCInOctets             integer
Tunnel100_ifHCOutOctets            integer
Tunnel1_ifHCInOctets               integer
Tunnel1_ifHCOutOctets              integer
Tunnel2_ifHCInOctets               integer
Tunnel2_ifHCOutOctets              integer
YYCIX_Gi0/0/1_ifHCInOctets         integer
YYCIX_Gi0/0/1_ifHCOutOctets        integer

> show tag keys from "monitor usage";
name: monitor usage
tagKey
------
agent_host
host
rtr_name
sw_name
```

Comment: Might be useful to show your schema with example values.
One must use the field name in the derivative.
One must `.groupBy(tag_name)` to calculate the derivative per interface.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay for the response. I have edited my post to include the measurement information. Could you explain more on the groupBy method? I read the document but I can't fully understand it. I am not from the programming background so I might miss key concepts..

Comment: in measurement (table) "monitor usage" the fields are the actual data which you use for calculations. Tags you can view as identifiers for each row (set of fields). You can have different sets of the same fields belonging to different hosts. Do `select sum(Envision_Po1.891_ifHCInOctets) from "monitor usage"` to get the total of all hosts together (1 value). Do `select sum(Envision_Po1.891_ifHCInOctets) from "monitor usage" group by host` to get 1 value per host in the results. Substitute `sum` for whatever function you need.